# Sonata Admin Dashboard: configure actions per entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm using the `SonataAdminBundle` as base for an administration interface for a Symfony2 (v2.0.x) powered website.

Entities which are added to the dashboard in SonataAdmin have the following actions by default:

- add
- list

This works fine for most entities, however the website has a few entities for which data is not added via the admin interface - i.e. they are entered from the public facing website. Administrators only need to view them ("list" action in dashboard), edit them or delete them. Administrators should not be able to add data to these entities.

Is there a way to configure which actions are displayed next to individual entities in SonataAdmin dashboard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `EntityAdmin` class add following

```
public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
  $collection->remove('create');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

To remove a single route from your `Admin` class, use

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
    {
        $collection->remove('edit');
    }
```

In **Symfony 2.1+**, you might use [`clearExcept`](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/routing.html#removing-a-route) to remove all routes *except* the ones given, like this:

```
public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
  $collection->clearExcept(array('list', 'edit', 'delete', 'batch'))
}
```

This has the advantage of keeping your actions as they are in case of new actions being added to `SonataAdminBundle`.

In **Symfony 2.0**, there is a similar [undocumented](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/commit/0c18ea197af7b3e73119156b310676fe680257d9) function as well (thanks Jeroen):

```
public function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
  $collection->removeAllExcept(array('list', 'edit', 'delete', 'batch'))
}
```

Comment: `$collection->clearExcept(array('list'))` works for me in order to leave only list option.