# Sonata Admin: How to remove "Add New" button from dashboard only?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration-files, sonata-admin, dashboard

I'm using Symfony 2.7 with Sonata Admin Bundle to manage some products and product images. I used the Sonata Admin Cookbook recipe: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/cookbook/recipe_file_uploads.html for images.

Because an image must have a product id associated with it, I want to disable the "Add New" Image link from the Sonata admin dashboard and from the top toolbar, so any uploaded image will have an associated product. Actually the only place where images should be allowed to be added is in the product add/edit page.

I've tried to remove the route like this, according to some answers found here: [Sonata Admin Dashboard: configure actions per entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587431/sonata-admin-dashboard-configure-actions-per-entity)

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer(); 

    if ($container->get('request')->get('_route') == 'sonata_admin_dashboard') {
        $collection->remove('create');
    }
}
```

But this solution is not good, because, if the cache is initialized when I access the admin dashboard, the route gets removed everywhere, but if the cache is initialized on a different page, then the route will be present on all pages, including dashboard, because Sonata Admin validates in templates if the route exists when displaying the link.

So, I need the route to exist and to remove the link. Can this be done using configuration or I have to rewrite the templates?

Answer (score 15):

In your admin class :

```
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->remove('create');
}
```

You can also remove Delete, Show etc ...

Check : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/routing.html#removing-a-single-route

Comment: This removes the `add`/`create` button at all.

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: eg this also removes the create button in a collection form field not dashboard only

Answer (score 8):

Try this in the admin class:

```
public function getDashboardActions() {
    $actions = parent::getDashboardActions();
    unset($actions['create']);
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: This name of this method is getActionButtons in SonataAdminBundle 
 3.4+

Answer (score 7):

In the following you can see a list of options to hide Sonatadmin functions:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->remove('create');
    $collection->remove('edit');
    $collection->remove('delete');
    $collection->remove('show');
    $collection->remove('export');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sonata admin configuration where you define your admins, remove the "group" tag. It looks something like this.

```
services:
    sonata.admin.images:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\ImageAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Manage images" }
        arguments:
            ...
```

(remove `group: "Content"` or whatever you have your group set as)

This will put your image admin in a separate block called "default".

Then, explicitly define which blocks you show on the dashboard, leaving out "default":

```
sonata_admin:
    dashboard:
        groups:
            Content: ~
            AnotherGroup: ~
```

Comment: Thank you for your time answering my question. Indeed, this is a method to get rid of the "Add New" link from my dashboard, but it would also remove the "List" link and I want the listing to be accessible. Further, this doesn't remove the link in the top toolbar.